# Agile Toolkit 500 error after install

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

I have installed agile toolkit on CentOS 6(php 5.3) lamp stack and when I pull up the index.php start page, it gives me a 500 error.

Comment: Nice. You should add answer to your own question after 24 hours I guess and accept it. That will give you +score and also will mark this question as answered.

Comment: Please @Ralanyo add your own answer below and accept it. That will give you bonus and also this question will not show up as unanswered all the time :)

Comment: I moved solution into a community-wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Went into the error logs and found the following error.

SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File: /public_html/index.php" is writeable by group

Basically that means the permissions on the index.php file need to be changed. I change them to 644 and all works well.